# Code not refreshing every few seconds

Tags: android, timer, android-timepicker

```
  String data ="";
        @Override   
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                        WifiManager mainWifiObj;
                        mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
                            class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
                            {
                                public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
                                {
                                }
                            }       

                        WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
                        registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

                        List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults(); int signalLevel = 

    0; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            data = wifiScanList.get(8).toString();

      TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(sb); 
                setContentView(tv); 
}
     handler.post(runnable);




I want to add my timer such that this code should run 5 times and it should run every 2 seconds. I am new to android. I found the timer code from the internet, but whenever and whichever code i try to implement, it gives me error. Basically, I think I am not adding the code at proper place.
```

But, I am unaware, where should I keep it. In the oncreate method or the `onCreate` method should be between the `run()`.

I am new so asked this question. Can anyone please help me out.

Here, the answers given run but I am unable to print the code

Comment: What you want to do exactly every 5 seconds ??

Comment: I am collecting the signal strength from wifi every 5 seconds. My code is working but i want it every 5 seconds.

Comment: Keep in mind that process will drain your battery.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private Handler handler; 

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                 handler.postDelayed(this, 2000); //2 seconds
                 //////Process to be executed every 2 seconds ////


              WifiManager mainWifiObj;
              mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
              class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
                   public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                   }
                }

                WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();


                   //////////
              } 
         };

        //start it with:
         handler.post(runnable);

    }
```

Comment: Your code is correct i suppose. I got the idea. But I have something to print. I have edited 3 lines into my code. I am unable to print anything. If the error is removed, then nothing is there in output. Can u pls suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override   
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
     handler.postDelayed(this, 2000); //2 seconds

    WifiManager mainWifiObj;
            mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
            class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
                   public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                   }
                }

                WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();

  } 
          }; }}

          //start it with:
           handler.post(runnable);
```

hope this helps..

Comment: Your code is correct i suppose. I got the idea. But I have something to print. I have edited 3 lines into my code. I am unable to print anything. If the error is removed, then nothing is there in output. Can u pls suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BroadcastReceiver that handles wifi connection changes.

To be more precise, you will want to create a class - say NetWatcher:

```
public class NetWatcher extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //here, check that the network connection is available. If yes, start your service. If not, stop your service.
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
   if (info != null) {
       if (info.isConnected()) {
           //start service
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
           startService(intent);
       }
       else {
           //stop service
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
           stopService(intent);
       }
   }
}}
```

Also, in your AndroidManifest, you need to add the following lines:

```
<receiver android:name="Yourpakege name.NetWatcher">
 <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

also more info  :  http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/monitor-wifi-status-and-information.html